# find xargs and curl give an error with -C- option

Tags: find, curl, xargs

This command works fine

```
find ~/mypath -name *.fstq -print|xargs curl -u sdd:dsdsd ftp://ftp.dsdd.nsdh.com/sdsds/ -T
```

but when I add

```
find ~/mypath -name *.fstq -print|xargs curl -C- -u sdd:dsdsd ftp://ftp.dsdd.nsdh.com/sdsds/ -T
```

I get an error message

```
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 451
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

any ideas how I can use resume (-C-) option with this pipe?

Comment: Can you add an "echo" between the | and xargs, to see what command it's actually running?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there a space after the -C, like "-C -"?

Comment: You are right, I tried using the space after but it produced the same error regardless of the fact.

Comment: You are probably uploading fastq files for publishing. I seem to remember that there are certain restrictions to the FTP servers (maybe they do not allow reading uploaded files and thus the SIZE command will fail). So before you blame the command try uploading to a FTP server you have full control over.